# Changing CSS properties of elements in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

Here is what my typical field looks like...

```
<input class='live-field' type=color data-el='#header' data-prop='background'>
```

Every field has class `live-field`, attribute `data-el` targetted element(s) selector and `data-prop` with property to change.

**Every time the value in input is changed I want the CSS property `data-prop` of element(s) selected by `data-el` to be changed to value of input.**

Right now I have this...

```
$('.live-field').change(function(){
  var $t = $(this);
  $( $t.data('el') ).css( $t.data('prop'), $t.val() )
});
```

Apparently this wont work coz `$( $t.data('el') )` will look for elements in the doc not in iFrame...

Here's my plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/uJcSwtE2xheJnS1vOdde?p=preview

For example... If I change value of this input...

```
<input class='live-field' type=color data-el='#header' data-prop='background'>
```

to `#f00`, the background color of element `#header` **in iframe** should be changed to `#f00` (red).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's `.contents()` method to access the iFrame DOM, so long as the iframe shares the same domain as the interactive content. Changing your onChange event to use the following code should do the trick:

```
$('.live-field').change(function(){
  var $t = $(this);
  $('#iframe').contents().find( $t.data('el') ).css( $t.data('prop'), $t.val() )
});
```

Edit for clarification: The iFrame and your inputs *must* share the same domain, otherwise the browser will not allow this type of functionality. See [this article on Same-Origin Policy for more info on why.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)